# Room RxJava2 update UI with Flowable<List<T>> when user makes a query or changes the filter

Tags: android, rx-java2, android-room

Using the filter below when i insert or delete row(s) Flowable updates as it should.

```
 val disposable = tasksRepository.getTasks(forceUpdate = false)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .flatMap { listTask ->
                    Flowable.fromIterable(listTask)
                            .filter {
                                when (currentFiltering) {
                                    TasksFilterType.ALL_TASKS -> true
                                    TasksFilterType.ACTIVE_TASKS -> it.isActive
                                    TasksFilterType.COMPLETED_TASKS -> it.isCompleted
                                }
                            }.toList().toFlowable()
                }

                .subscribe(
                        {
                            // onNext
                            nextValue: List<Task> ->
                            tasks.value = nextValue
                        },

                        {
                            // onError
                            error ->
                            tasks.value = emptyList()    
                        }
                )
```

However, i wonder if it's possible to get another emission just by changing filter or adding a query String that user enters or should i write a `Single<List<Task>>` and subscribe to this whenever user filters or enters a query keyword?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `combineLatest()`. The resulting observable emits when any of the source observables emits.

Example:

```
private val currentFilter = BehaviorProcessor.createDefault<TasksFilterType>(TasksFilterType.ALL_TASKS)
private val userQuery = BehaviorProcessor.createDefault<String>("")


val disposable = Flowable
        .combineLatest(getTasks(), currentFilter, userQuery) { listTask, filter, query ->
            listTask
                .filter { // filter tasks by filter
                    when (filter) {
                        TasksFilterType.ALL_TASKS -> true
                        TasksFilterType.ACTIVE_TASKS -> it.isActive
                        TasksFilterType.COMPLETED_TASKS -> it.isCompleted
                    }
                }
                .filter { task -> task.contains(query) } // filter tasks by query
        }
        .subscribeOn(...)
        ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer it works but i have a question what is the purpose of using BehaviorProcessor instead of any other kind like Subject that has onNext(String) method?

Comment: @Thracian, I randomly picked them just for demonstration. You can use any `Publisher` you want. Just a quick note: `Subjects` are not `Publishers`.